# Extracting info from dynamic page element in Python without "clicking" to make visible?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, lxml

For the life of me I can't think of a better title...

I have a Python WebDriver-based scraper that goes to Google, enters a local search such as *chiropractors+new york+ny*, which, after clicking on *More chiropractors+New York+NY*, ends up on a page like [this](https://www.google.com.ni/?gws_rd=cr&ei=5EooVoLzMsKmNvPgoBA#q=chiropractors%2BNew%20York,%20NY&rflfq=1&rlha=0&tbm=lcl)

[image]

The goal of the scraper is to grab the phone number and **full address (including suite# etc.**) of each of the 20 results on such a results page. In order to do so, I need to have WebDriver click 20 entries needs to be clicked on the bring up an overlay over the Google Map:

[image]

This is mighty slow. Were it not having to trigger each of these overlays, I would be able to do everything up to that point with the much faster `lxml`, by going straight to the ultimate URL of the results page and then extracting via XPath. But I appear to be stuck with not being able to get data from the overlay without first clicking on the link that brings up the overlay.

Is there a way to get the data out of this page element without having to click the associated links?